# Vector/Array to integer

Tags: objective-c++

```
-(void)userShow{
    xVal = new vector<double>();
    yVal = new vector<double>();
    xyVal = new vector<double>();
    xxVal = new vector<double>();
    value = new vector<double>();
for(it = xp->begin(); it != xp->end(); ++it){
    xVal->push_back(it->y);
    xxVal->push_back(it->x);

}
for(it = yp->begin(); it != yp->end(); ++it){
    xyVal->push_back(it->x);
    yVal->push_back(it->y);
}

    for (int i = 0; i < xVal->size(); i++){
        int c = (*xVal)[i];
        for(int i = 0; xyVal[i] < xxVal[i]; i++){
           double value = yVal[c-1] + (yVal[c] - yVal[c-1])*(xxVal[i] - xyVal[c-1])/(xyVal[c] - xyVal[c-1]);
            yVal->push_back(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I am having an issue with the `double value = ...` part of my code. I get three errors saying `invalid operands to binary expression ('vector<double>' and 'vector<double>')` pointing to the `c`.

should `int c = (*xVal)[i];` be `double c = (*xVal)[i];` when i try to use double i get 6 errors saying `Array subscript is not an integer`. Which means I need to convert the array into an integer. How am I getting an array if I am using vectors? Just a lot of confusion at the moment.

Not really sure if i really need to explain what the code is supposed to do, but if it helps. I am trying to get it so it take two vectors splits the vectors x and y's into x and y. then take the y of xp and the y of yp and put them together. but because xp and yp vectors do not match i need to use the for loop and the double value algorithm to get a decent set of numbers.

Comment: Is this C++, or Objective-C?  That doesn't look like a C++ function signature.

Comment: Why dynamically-allocated vectors?

Comment: Its a mix of both I guess. ipad dev.

Comment: If you use objective-c, roll-back your question (from the edits) and use objective-c tag..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `c` is fine. The problem really is in `double value = ..`, as your compiler says. You have pointers, so you can't access the array's elements like this:

```
double value = yVal[c-1] + ...
```

It must be

```
double value = (*yVal)[c-1] +
```

The same for `xyVal`, `xxVal`, etc. You need to fix the whole inner `for` loop.

---

But why you allocate the `vector`s like this...? Is there any reason to use `new`? This is so error prone. I'd use just

```
vector<double> xVar;
```

instead of

```
xVal = new vector<double>();
```

And then use `.` instead of `->` combined with `*`. It so much easier.

---

Ah, forgot about the question for `c` - no, it should not be `double`. You can't use floating point numbers for indices. Also, if `xVal` is supposed to contain integer numbers (so that they can be used for indices), why don't you just declare the `vector` as `vector< int >` instead of `vector< double >`? I don't what's the logic in your program, but it looks like it(the logic) should be improved, IMO.

Comment: i used `new` because when i try it your way it gives me Local declaration of xVal hides instance variable. ! Member reference type 'vector<double>' is not a pointer.

Comment: @KirilKirov I did what you said changed it to this `double value = (*yVal)[c-1] + ((*yVal)[c] - (*yVal)[c-1])*(xxVal[i] - (*xyVal)[c-1])/((*xyVal)[c] - (*xyVal)[c-1]);` and now i am getting invalid operands to binary expression ('vector<double>' and 'double')`

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: You still have `xxVal[i]` - change to `(*xxVal)[i]`

Comment: Then just use other name..it seems like you have a member, named `xVal`. Ah, sorry, but this design seems totally wrong. As far as I see, you still haven't changed the `xxVal` access. Fix it.

Comment: opps figured it out.. why does `            yVal->push_back(value);` give me an issue with `local declaration of 'value' hides instance variable`

Comment: This is totally different now.. Look for some global variables, that are named `value`. It sounds clear enough.

Comment: @Kiril: Global? Global instance variables?

Comment: (facepalm) `yVal->push_back(value);` you know, that this `value` is pointer to `std::vector< double >`, right?

Comment: @Tomalak - I don't see class specifier in front of the function definition, so I decided it's global. And I wasn't sure if "instance variable" is always a member variable, if that's what you mean :?

Comment: I can't wait until I look back at this and can face palm this myself. Can you explain more why this is a face palm..

Comment: `yVal` is container: `std::vector< double >`. This is supposed to be a `vector` (array), containing `double`s, right? Floating point numbers, in other words. So, `push_back` is supposed to "push" a `double` inside this container, not a pointer to another vector (`value` is pointer to `std::vector< double >`). The compiler may miss such error, as pointer is just an `integer` number, and there's an implicit cast from `int` to `double`. In other words, if this compiles at all, will be absolutely wrong. You'll add some value, which will be the address of the `value` vector, converted to `double`

Comment: @KirilKirov what should i do then? `double value = (*yVal)[c-1] + ((*yVal)[c] - (*yVal)[c-1])*((*xxVal)[i] - (*xyVal)[c-1])/((*xyVal)[c] - (*xyVal)[c-1]);yNewVal->push_back(value);` is what i changed it too but not sure what to do with the `yNewVal` do i make it a vector<double>? `value` isn't getting any variables from the equation it looks like as well...

Comment: @JohnRiselvato - oh, my bad. The `double value` inside the for loop hides the `value`, that is declared as pointer to vector. What means, that `value isn't getting any variables from the equation`? The statement crashes or the value is `0`, or what?

Comment: yeah it returns i guess null. There isn't anything inside of it. When i run my program if i don't put a break before when i call value in another function, it will crash. also it shows a weird  -naFFFF00FFF as the value if you hover it with xcode.